# Sequence of invertible operators converging in norm to an injective but not surjective operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space. Can you find a sequence $A_n$ invertible and $A$ injective but not surjective in $B(X)$ such that $A_n\rightarrow A$ in norm?

I know that such an $A$ must not be bounded below, since then there is a uniform bound on $\Vert A_n^{-1}\Vert$. This implies $A$ would be invertible.

Comment: There are Banach spaces where it is possible: take $X=\mathscr{C}([0;1])$, $A_n(f)=(Id+\frac{1}{n}f)$, $A$ is the multiplication by $Id$, injective but not surjective.

Comment: @Mindlack  Okay sure. The example I'm most interested in is $X=B(\mathcal H)$. Your example can probably be adapted to that by considering multiplication by some injective operator. Does that seem right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=L^2[0,\infty)$ and let $Af = e^{-x}f$. $A$ is injective, but not surjective. Let $A_n f = (e^{-x}\chi_{[0,n]}+e^{-n}\chi_{[n,\infty)})f$. Each $A_n$, $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, is invertible, and
$$
        (A-A_n)f = (e^{-n}-e^{-x})\chi_{[n,\infty)}f,
$$
which gives $\|A-A_n\| \le e^{-n}$.

Comment: A little simpler might be $A_n f = (1+e^{-n}) e^{-x} f$.

Comment: @NateEldredge : You should post an answer with that example. The simpler the better.

Comment: Nice. It seems something like this (meaning letting $A$ be multiplication by some operator) could work with $X=B(\mathcal H)$. Could you please comment on that?

Comment: @RickSanchez : Yes, that's the way I deliberately chose it based on your comment.

Comment: One more question... I now see how this works in most concrete spaces, but in a general Banach space, it doesn't seem so clear to me.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Also, to make sure I am totally clear, I want $X$ to be $B(\mathcal H)$. Meaning I want operators in $B(B(\mathcal H))$. I'm not sure if that was conveyed correctly.